# FireDac MySql Connector.ExecSql wont work

Tags: mysql, delphi, stored-procedures, firedac

MySqlConnector.ExecSql(SqlScript.Text); is my line in code.

SqlScript.Text is loaded with

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS timecard.VersionControl (  
  `Table` varchar(30) NOT NULL,             
  `Version` DECIMAL NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY (`Table`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;     

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS timecard.UpdateVersionControl;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE timecard.UpdateVersionControl(IN `Tab` VARCHAR(30), IN `Ver` DECIMAL)
BEGIN                                 
  if EXISTS(SELECT * FROM timecard.VersionControl WHERE `Table` = Tab) THEN
    UPDATE timecard.VersionControl SET `Version`=Ver WHERE `Table`=Tab;
  else        
    INSERT INTO timecard.VersionControl (`Table`, `Version`) VALUES (Tab, Ver);
  END IF;
END$$  

DELIMITER ;
```

I cant get an error code form the IDE to know where the script is failing.

If I run the script in MySql workbench it works fine.

If a run the Table creation as one script and then the Procedure as a separate script if works fine.

Why cant I run as one ExecSql script?

Comment: FireDAC's author has been quite active lately on SO under the tag "DaSoft", so if you get lucky, he may answer you here.  If you don't get a response here you might try asking in EMBA's FireDAC newsgroup, https://forums.embarcadero.com/forum.jspa?forumID=502

Answer (score 4):

TFDConnection.ExecSQL allows to execute a single SQL command. But you trying to execute SQL script. For that you should use TFDScript:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Executing_SQL_Scripts_(FireDAC)

Comment: Bravo!  I thought you might have an answer like that.